# Await user confirmation for AlertDialog for Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to wait for user confirmation before executing a certain piece of code. This is where I build and show the AlertDialog:

```
private bool AskForCommand()
{
    bool userOK = false;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.SetPositiveButton("Yes", (sender, args) =>
    {
        userOK = true;
    })
    .SetNegativeButton("No", (sender, args) =>
    {
        userOK = false;
    })
    .SetMessage("Send vocal command now?")
    .SetTitle("System Message");
    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        dialog.Show();
    });

    return userOK;
}
```

and here is where i call the Method:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exactSpeech))
{
    bool userOK = false;
    try
    {
        userOK = AskForCommand();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TODO: catch
    }

    if (cfg.InstantSendVocal || userOK)
        SendCommandToBoard(exactSpeech);
}
```

the problem is that the alert is shown AFTER the method "SendCommandToBoard".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put below code in the `SetPositiveButton` callback

     `dialog.SetPositiveButton("Yes", (sender, args) =>
        {
           if (cfg.InstantSendVocal)
               SendCommandToBoard(exactSpeech); 
        }`

Forget about the Boolean variable called userOK